# HTTP request: works when opening url in browser, but requires authorization when requested in code

Tags: node.js, authorization, httprequest

I want to process the response from the following url:

> http://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/search?format=json&address=salzburg

I get a valid result when I open it in my browser, but the following response when I query it in my code:

```
var url = 'http://services.gisgraphy.com/geocoding/search?format=json&address=salzburg'
http.get(url, function(res) {
                var body = '';
                res.on('data', function(data) {
                    body += data;
                });
                res.on('end', function() {
                   console.log(body);
                });
            });
```

Response:

```
   <html>
    <head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How is the server able to distinguish between the two kinds of request?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct headers solves this:

```
var http=require('http');

var headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'utf8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en'
};

var request = http.get(
    {
        host: 'services.gisgraphy.com',
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/geocoding/search?format=json&address=salzburg',
        headers: headers
    }, 
    (res) => {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
           console.log(body);
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Can someone tag the question with `jquery` or `requirejs` or whatever is being used here?

Comment: it seems to be something along the line of nodejs, I will tag it.